# How to pull specific key - value in python

Tags: python, dictionary

In a Python script, I have a dictionary:

`dict = [{'entity': 'Mexican', 'type': 'cuisine', 'startIndex': None, 'endIndex': None, 'score': None}]`

Now, i would like to pull only the key `entity`, so I can store the key's value `Mexican` in a string variable.

Comment: What have you tried? What is the problem? Why not simply `dict[0]['entity']`?

Comment: By the way: `dict` is not a dictionary but a list containing a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

To access a value in dictionary, query the dictionary with its key.
Ex-

```
dict = { 1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c' }
dict[1]
'a'
dict[2]
'b'
```

But in your code you added the dictionary inside a List.

```
[{'entity': 'Mexican', 'type': 'cuisine', 'startIndex': None, 'endIndex': None, 'score': None}]
```

The square braces are surrounding the Dictionary here. So, this dictionary will be the first item in the list named *dict*
So to access the value of the *entity* key present in the dictionary, you need to first access the List value and then access the Dictionary key value.

Thus to achieve this use the below code.

```
dict[0]['entity']
```

Here, `dict[0]` returns the dictionary object and `['entity']` on that returns the value from the dictionary object.